# Formula for $\tan(a + b)$ by complex numbers?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

**Edit**
Sorry, I meant that in the first equation we take the Im[] part no the Re[] part. Fixed now.

We can find $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$ by expressing 
$$
\sin(x+y) = Im[e^{(x+y)\sqrt{-1}}] = Im[e^{x\sqrt{-1}} * e^{y\sqrt{-1}}] = Im[(\cos(x) + i\sin(x))  \times (\cos(y) + i\sin(y))] = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)
$$
and can we show 
$$
\tan(A+B) = \frac{\tan(A) + \tan(B)}{1 - \tan(A) \tan(B)}
$$
In a similar way?

My main problem is how to divide the parts:
$$
\frac{Im[\sin(A+B)]}{Re[\cos(A+B)]}
$$
Because we need to take the imaginary part (the $\sin$) from $\sin(A+B)$ and the real part (the $\cos$) from $\cos(A+B)$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use the fact that $\tan(u+v)=\sin(u+v)/\cos(u+v)$ and just transform until you get the identity. It's by far the easiest way to get the identity. Also, I strongly suggest you write $i$ instead of $\sqrt{-1}$ in the future, as it's much more clear what you mean by that. Otherwise someone might believe that you mean $-i$, as  $(-i)^2=i^2=-1$.

Comment: I tried to write `\i` in the latex formula, but my equation did not render properly (website could not parse it for some reason). Thats why I used $\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: @Scounged so of course I agree with you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that with $i=\sqrt {-1}$$$\cos (A+B)+i\sin (A+B)=e^{i(A+B)}=e^{iA}\cdot e^{iB}=(\cos A +i\sin A)\cdot(\cos B+i\sin B)$$

So we have $$\tan (A+B)=\frac {Im(e^{i(A+B)})}{Re(e^{i(A+B)})}=\frac {\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}{\cos A\cos B-\sin A\sin B}=\frac {\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A \tan B}$$Where the last is obtained by dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos A\cos B$

That probably adds little to what you already know, but it gives a quick way of spotting the pattern for tan when you are adding more than two angles. You get odd products on top - one or three or five - and even products on the bottom - zero or two or four. The signs alternate so products of one, five, nine are positive and products of three, seven are negative in the numerator. In the denominator products of zero or four or eight are positive and products of two or six are negative. That's because $i^2=-1; i^4=1$. Work it out and see how it works.

Comment: thank you, for me the "dividing numerator and denominator by cos(A)cos(B)" was the key part.